# Computing probability for uniform and conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Problem:** Let $X$ have the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$, and let the conditional distribution of $Y$, given $X=x$, be $\mathcal{U}(0,x)$. Find $P(X+Y \geq 1)$.

> **Question:** From uniform distribution $\frac{1}{b-a}$, I get $f_X(x)=1$ and $f_{Y|X}(Y|X=x)=\frac{1}{x}$. I am not sure how to find the probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
P(X+Y\geq 1)=P(Y\geq 1-X)=\int_{0}^1 P(Y\geq 1-x\mid X=x) f_{X}(x)\, dx\tag{0}
$$
by the law of total probability. Observe that
$$
P(Y\geq 1-x\mid X=x)=\frac{x-(1-x)}{x}=\frac{2x-1}{x}\quad (x\ge 1/2)
$$
and $P(Y\geq 1-x\mid X=x)=0$ otherwise since $Y\mid X=x$ is uniform on $(0,x)$. Hence returning to equation $(0)$ we have that
$$
P(X+Y\geq 1)=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{2x-1}{x}\, dx
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated $P(Y \geq 1-x | X=x)$ in more detail? And why $ x \geq \frac{1}{2}$?